# I want to Change Hotbar-Color

Tags: eclipse, themes

Hey i just already installed a Color Theme for Eclipse so mush of Eclipse is now dark. The last thing is the Hotbar
i have no idea what I can do to change color to black.

I am using Windows 10
Already tried to change system color.
But not working:

[image: this my eclipse]

Comment: Please, can you add some details about your tries? What were the steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the color of the main and right-click/popup/context menu can not be changed by Eclipse in Windows. But you can **set a dark theme/design in Windows** for all applications.

Comment: how i do this on Windows 10

Comment: @RobinSeerig For example, select the _High Contrast Black_ theme [as described here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/high-contrast-themes-windows). But you probably want to install a more beautiful dark Windows 10 theme than the _High Contrast Black_ theme.